# Form getting auto submit when i click add new column button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

i am working on a form for keeping records of expenses, using HTML and jQuery which is connected to the database..

the problem is when i click "Add" button, it should add new column but instead it auto submits the form.

---

HTML

```
<form name="myForm" action="mysql_connection.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Expense     &#160&#160&#160&#160&#160&#160
                            &#160&#160&#160&#160&#160&#160
                            &#160&#160&#160&#160&#160&#160
                            &#160&#160&#160&#160&#160&#160 
                Amount
                <br/>
                <input type="text" name="expense" id="expense" />
                <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" />
                <br/>

            </td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="add">Add</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

---

jQuery

```
        $(document).ready(

        function() {
            $('button.add').live('click',

            function() {
                $(this)
                    .closest('tr')
                    .clone()
                    .appendTo('table');
                $(this)
                    .text('Remove')
                    .removeClass('add')
                    .addClass('remove');
            });
            $('button.remove').live('click',

            function() {
                $(this)
                    .closest('tr')
                    .remove();
            });
            $('input:text').each(

            function() {
                var thisName = $(this).attr('name'),
                    thisRrow = $(this)
                        .closest('tr')
                        .index();
                $(this).attr('name', 'row' + thisRow + thisName);
                $(this).attr('id', 'row' + thisRow + thisName);
            });
        });
```

here is the form
[**CODE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pratik_udeshi91/J89TF/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your `<button>` element to be a `<button type="button">` element then your solution works correctly.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gg5FL/1/)</kbd>

The [default type for a `<button>` element is `Submit`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#attr-button-type) and so that is why it was causing the form to Submit.

Answer (score 0):

```
            $('button.add').live('click',

            function() {
                $(this)
                    .closest('tr')
                    .clone()
                    .appendTo('table');
                $(this)
                    .text('Remove')
                    .removeClass('add')
                    .addClass('remove');
                return false;
            });
```

add "return false" to end of click function

Answer (score 0):

check link http://jsfiddle.net/J89TF/1/

Use  `e.preventDefault();`

I think you should implement @Nunners solution. B'coz its clean code.

Comment: If u satisfies with the answer please mark as answer so that it can help others

Comment: @Pratik While this answer works, it's really not a good/right solution. First you markup the button as a submitter and then you stop the default action. The better way is to markup a button as a normal button using type=button. See the answer from Nunners.

Comment: Right @alexanderfarkas :)